# What does insider trade with zero price mean?

Tags: stocks

I was checking a **Chronological Insider Trades** report and noticed these buys with zero price. Are these bonuses given to board members as company stocks?

[image: trade list]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are the exercise of [warrants](https://geoinvesting.com/form-4-filings-insider-buying-101/) allowing an employee to obtain stock at no cost.

> For example, insiders often own stock options or warrants awarded to them by their company (approved by the Board). The initial grant of these derivatives is first recorded in the Derivative section of a Form 4.  But when/if insiders convert them (also referred to as *exercise*) into ownership of common stock at predetermined prices (usually below market prices and sometimes at zero), the transaction shows up in the Non-Derivative table.

Comment: Does this affect the shares outstanding? Or is the stock secured by the warrant already counted?